# PHP пропустить аргументы функции

Tags: php

Добрый день.
Есть функция:

```
function lol($a = 1, $b = 2, $c = 3) { 
{
```

Как можно вызвать эту функцию, изменив только 3ий аргумент, без указания 1го и 2го? Дабы не писать подобный код: `lol(1,2,4)`

Просто есть функции с длинными дефолтными аргументами, и ищу способ как их не указать.

**Update:** постараюсь сформулировать понятнее. Допустим в функции, по стандарту аргументы `$a = 123456789, $b = 123`

Как мне вызвать `lol($b = 321)` пропустив, и не указав `$a`? (т.к. оно длинное)

Comment: вопрос непонятен...версия PHP какая?

Comment: не проще ли писать `lol(0,0,4)` и в функции `$a = (!$a) ? 1 : $a;` ?

Comment: @Alex проще, но я вот и задал вопрос, чтобы узнать, возможно есть более корректный способ.

Comment: все способы передачи аргументов - http://php.net/manual/ru/functions.arguments.php

Comment: в зависимости от решаемой задачи решение может быть разное....... например если в основном вызывается без параметров и изредка нужно вызывать указав лишь `$b`, то проще его сделать первым по счету.... или сделать отдельную функцию, где аргумент  будет `$b` но внутри которого вызывается функция с тремя аргументами

Comment: Кстати можно попробовать поиграть с массивами и передавать в функцию один массив который может быть разной величины под ваши вкусы. Но я не знаю ваших требований и задач и не могу предложить решение на их основе.

Comment: Поддерживаю Telion и Алексея Шиманского с массивом

Comment: @DaemonHK для этого есть vote up у комментария)

Comment: @Alex, я уже)))

Comment: @Amidamaru если Вам дан подходящий ответ, пожалуйста отметьте его как [решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), чтобы Ваш вопрос не висел в открытых.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> function lol($a = 1, $b = 2, $c = 3) {}
> ```
>
> Как мне вызвать `lol($b = 321)` пропустив, и не указав `$a`?

**Никак.**

[Описание и все способы передачи аргументов](http://php.net/manual/ru/functions.arguments.php)

Comment: кстати, в 5.6 когда-то обещали ввести `default` для функций. Обманули?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский [данное предложение было отклонено](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/skipparams), а жаль

Comment: Ну не знаю. Может и правильно. Костыль же))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский на костылях порой со временем рождается разумное решение) а пока получаем несколько "лишних" строк в коде

Answer (score 1):

А задать туда `NULL` или `0` подойдет? Вы можете задать `(0,0,4)`, коротко и сразу видно что нули не заданы. В функции проверка заданы или нет.

Взятый из английского ресурса [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9166914/using-default-arguments-in-a-function):

```
function foo($blah, $x = null, $y = null) {
    if (null === $x) {
        $x = "some value";
    }

    if (null === $y) {
        $y = "some other value";
    }

    code here!

}
```

Но вызывать все так же нужно с определенным кол-вом параметров.

```
foo('blah', null, 'non-default y value');
```

Где можно задать значения, а можно оставить по умолчанию, как второй параметр тут.

Comment: Нужно оставить их стандартное значение, 1, 2, но $b = 4

Comment: @Amidamaru что значит стандартные? Откуда они должны браться если вы их не хотите задавать? Или они совершенно всегда такими будут? Тогда посто задайте их в функции как 1 и 2, в чем проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Как Вам уже говорили:

```
function lol($a=null,$b=null,$c=null){
    $a=!empty($a)?$a:123456789;
    $b=!empty($b)?$b:123;
    $c=!empty($c)?$c:1;
}
```

Вызывать так: lol(null,345)

В PHP 5.6+ появилось [Переменное количество аргументов](http://php.net/manual/ru/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list)

Comment: а теперь вызовите lol($b = 321) пропустив, и не указав $a как просит автор в своем вопросе

Comment: а это невозможно

Comment: @Alex ваш вопрос неясен. Если вы вызываете функцию вы должны указать все параметкы, даже если они заданы как ноль или что-либо еще. Если хотите сделать параметры стандартными и статическими то внутри функции напишите `$a = 123456789, $b = 123` но все равно вызывайте функцию с тремя параметрами.

Comment: @DaemonHK это и есть ответ )

Comment: `$a = $a ?? 12345`

Comment: @vp_arth это будет работать только в php7 (возможно стоит уточнить)

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете определить функцию с одним аргументом-массивом, а вызывать, передавая массив вместо параметров. Это самый простой способ эмуляции именнованных параметров.

Пример:

```
function f($options) {
    extract($options);  // добавить элементы массива в текущую область видимости
    echo $c;
}
```

Использование:

```
f(['c' => 42]);  // передаст в функцию число 42
```

---

<sub>Для удобства применяется функция [export](https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/function.extract.php), чтобы в одну строчку извлечь содержимое массива в текущую область видимости. Возможно, вы решите, что это способ порождает слишком много ошибок, если тщательно не документировать ваш код. В таком случае, можете выполнять присваивания вашим локальным переменным вручную или напрямую использовать элементы переданного массива, если функция небольшая.</sub>

<sub>В любом случае надо знать меру и не забывать о читаемости кода.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Один из вариантов, фасадировать функцию:

```
function lol($a = 1, $b = 2, $c = 3) {}
function lolС($c = 3) {return lol(1, 2, $c);}
```

Значимыми параметрами по умолчанию, вообще говоря, злоупотреблять не стоит.
В любом случае, имеет смысл замена магических чисел константами с осмысленными именами:

```
class A {
  const DEF_A = 1;
  const DEF_B = 2;
  function lol($a = self::DEF_A, $b = self::DEF_B) {}
}
```

тогда проблема передачи значений по умолчанию исчезает:

```
$a->lol(A::DEF_A, 3);
```

---

Ну и стандартное решение - самостоятельная реализация значений по умолчанию:

```
function lol($a = null, $b = null) {
  $a = $a ?? 1; // php7 coalesce syntax
  $b = $b ?? 2;
}
lol(null, 3);
```

Comment: а шо как константы, так сразу за классы хватаетесь? ;-)

Comment: Ну а куда их? Дефайнить что-ли? Мне спать пора, зачем такие ужасы?

Comment: `const` вне классов валидны еще с >= 5.3 $-) Но как не делай - все равно кошмар :)

Comment: А scope какой? Глобальный? В чём разница тогда?

Comment: Я хотел ещё, как вариант, интерфейс с параметрами заинжектить, но потом вспомнил, что у интерфейсов в php нет состояния и передумал.

Answer (score 0):

> Да, можно существенно сократить сигнатуру пользовательской функции, если использовать в качестве передаваемого аргумента ассоциативный массив, ключи которого будут именованы в соответствии с переменными из тела фунции. Звучит немного запутано, поэтому публикую поясняющий пример:

```
// Вызов с параметрами по умолчанию
foo();

// Вызов с любым параметром (остальные по умолчанию)
foo(['b' => 'Новый параметр']);

// Вызов со всеми новыми параметрами 
foo(['a' => 'Значение 1', 'b' => 'Значение 2', 'c' => 'Значение 3']);

function foo() {
    // Массив параметров по умолчанию
    $args = [
        'a' => 123456789,
        'b' => 123,
        'c' => 3
    ];

    extract($args);    

    foreach (func_get_args() as $array) {
        extract($array);
    }

    // И далее работаете с переменными $a, $b, $c
    echo '<pre>', var_dump($a, $b, $c), '</pre>';
}
```

> **Результаты:**

```
int(123456789)
int(123)
int(3)

int(123456789)
string(27) "Новый параметр"
int(3)

string(18) "Значение 1"
string(18) "Значение 2"
string(18) "Значение 3"
```

Comment: @Amidamaru [запостил ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/741698/185343)